# Custom validation 'on edit' rather than 'on submit'. ASP.NET, Kendo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, data-annotations

So, I have this DateRange custom validation attribute

```
public class DateRange : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            return (DateTime) value >= DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

And I have a field in my view (a Kendo Grid) where user submits date (some sort of a DatePicker);

For this DateTime in my viewModel

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DateRange(ErrorMessage = "Invalid date")]
[DisplayName("Expiration Date")]
public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
```

Right now it works like 'when user submits the model, it doesn't pass validation';

```
(product != null && ModelState.IsValid) //doesnt pass with invalid date
```

How I want it to work : that it would pop up the message 'Date should be bla-bla' and not let user submit until he enters valid date. I know it is possible because regex annotation does this kind of behavior for the other field.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you all kindly :)

Comment: Your `DateRange` attribute needs to implement `IClientValidatable` if you want client side validation. Examples [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/enabling-client-side-validation-on-custom-data-annotations-w/) and [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/23/custom-data-annotation-validator-part-ii-client-code.aspx) - the second one looks similar to what your after.

Comment: Thank you. I've checked out how Regex annotation is organised, and noticed it doesn't go the way these examples work, while providing the needed behavior. I'll resort to your links in case I don't manage to get a more straight-forward way of solving this without adding custom stuff.

Comment: You would not be able to use a `[RegularExpression]` attribute to determine if the date is greater than today's date, or any other built in validation attribute because they only accept constants as parameters, and `DateTime.Now` is not a constant